# How to nest more than one QUERY and supply one condition for all the queries

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-query-language

I am trying to nest Google Sheets queries but I can't seem to get it to work. I have a working formula but the problem is that it mixes students from different dates together. The formula is supposed to return all students between `TODAY()` and `TODAY()+3` but should first be done with `TODAY()` students then `TODAY()+1` etc. At the moment, it's listing all students from the specified dates first before moving to the nest sheet Students Level 2.

I resorted to trying to nest the queries and then supply one condition at the end which I haven't succeeded in doing yet. I need the queries to share the same condition at the end so that the list orders by date. Alternatively, if there is a way of manipulating my current formula to order by date is still OK.

Here is the working formula which I wish to manipulate, with your kind help:

```
={query('Students Level A'!A2:EC, " select EC where A is not null and not 
B contains '-' and EC>=date"""&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and 
EC<=date"""&TEXT(TODAY()+3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and not B matches '[\d- ] 
{5}' order by EC");
query('Students Level B'!A2:EC, " select EC where A is not null and not B 
contains '-' and EC>=date"""&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and 
EC<=date"""&TEXT(TODAY()+3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and not B matches '[\d- ] 
{5}' order by EC");
query('Students Level C'!A2:EC, " select EC where A is not null and not B 
contains '-' and EC>=date"""&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and 
EC<=date"""&TEXT(TODAY()+3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and not B matches '[\d- ] 
{5}' order by EC")}
```

I am looking for something along the lines of:

```
={query('Students Level A'!A2:EC);query('Students Level 
B'!A2:EC);query('Students Level C'!A2:EC), "select EC where A is not null 
and not B contains '-' and EC>=date"""&TEXT(TODAY(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and 
EC<=date"""&TEXT(TODAY()+3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&""" and not B matches '[\d- ] 
{5}' order by EC"}
```

In this formula, I nested the queries first, then supplied a single condition for all the queries after. But this formula won't work.

Answer (score 0):

you would need to do it like this:

```
=QUERY({{'Students Level A'!A2:B, 'Students Level A'!EC2:EC};
        {'Students Level B'!A2:B, 'Students Level B'!EC2:EC};
        {'Students Level C'!A2:B, 'Students Level C'!EC2:EC}}, 
 "select Col3 
  where Col1 is not null 
    and not Col2 contains '-' 
    and Col3 >= date '"&TEXT(TODAY(),   "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and Col3 <= date '"&TEXT(TODAY()+3, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
    and not Col2 matches '[\d- ] {5}' 
  order by Col3", 0)
```